# Why is the solution set of S={( x , y ) ∈ R^2 : y=ax+b } not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The solution set S of the equation y=ax+b, S={(x, y) ∈R^2: y=ax+b}, is not a vector space using regular vector addition and regular scalar multiplication.

I'm having a hard time understanding why that is and which axiom it violates. Let me know where I went wrong with my proofs.

Let a = 6 and b = 8, and y = 6(x) + 8

> Closed Under Addition:
> (u, 6u + 8) + (v, 6v + 8) = u + v + 6(u) + 6(v) + 16 = (u + v, 6u + 6v + 16) is in S

> Commutative:
> (u, 6u + 8) + (v, 6v + 8) = u + v + (6(u) + 6(v) + 16) = (v + 6v + 8) + (u + 6u + 8) = (v, 6u + 8)+ (u, 6u + 8)

> Associative Property: (u,6u+8) + [(v, 6v + 8) + w] = u + (6u + 8) + v + (6v + 8) + w = [u + + (6u + 8) + v + (6v + 8)]

> Additive Identity: (u, 6u+8) + (0,0) = u + 6u + 8 + 0 + 0 = (u, 6u + 8)

> Additive Inverse: (u,6u+8) + (-u, -(6u+8)) = u + 6u + 8 - u - 6u - 8 = 0

> Scalar multiplication: Let c be a scalar, c(u, 6u + 8) = cu + 6cu + 8c = (6cu, 6cu + 8c) is in S

> Distributive Property 1: c[(u, 6u + 8) + (v, 6v + 8)] = cu + cv + 6cu + 6cv + 16c = (cu, 6cu + 8c) + (cv, 6cv + 8c)

> Distributive Property 2: let d be a scalar, (c + d)(u, 6u + 8) = (c+d)(u + 6u + 8) = uc + 6cu + 8c + du + 6du + 8d = (cu, 6cu + 8d) + (du, 6du + 8d)

> Associative Property: c(du) = c(du + 6du + 8d) = cdu + 6cdu + 8cd = cd(u, 6u + 8)

> Scalar Identity: 1(u, 6u + 8) = 1(u + 6u + 8) = u + 6u + 8 = (u, 6u + 8)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is $(0,0)\in S$?

Comment: It is not closed under addition in your example:  $8+8=16$.

Comment: Also, in many of your calculations you have vectors equated to scalars.  This is impossible and a sure sign of error.

Comment: "*Closed Under Addition: (u, 6u + 8) + (v, 6v + 8) = u + v + 6(u) + 6(v) + 16 = (u + v, 6u + 6v + 18) is in S*"  What does it mean to be in $S$ again?  It means that it is a solution to $y=6x+8$... Is it true that $(6u+6v+18) = 6(u+v)+8$?  Or $(6u+6v+16)$ for that matter?

Comment: "*Scalar multiplication: Let c be a scalar, c(u, 6u + 8) = cu + 6cu + 8c = (6cu, 6cu + 8c) is in S*"  Is $(6cu+8c)$ really equal to $6(cu)+8$?  It feels like you are just throwing around the phrase "*is in $S$*" without actually checking whether or not it is, or even understanding what it means in the first place.

Comment: Here is how your first point *should* go:  $(u,6u+8) + (v, 6v+8) = (u+v,6u+8+6v+8) = (u+v, 6u+6v+16)$......  Note that I have no scalars after adding vectors.

Comment: You seem to forget that all vectors mentioned in the axioms of a vector space must lie in the vector space itself (here $S$). You purported additive identity and additive inverse are not valid because they do not satisfy this requirement. Also operating on these elements with the purported addition (which is the restriction to $S$ of the usual addition) is not possible because pairs formed using them do not belong to the domain ($S\times S$) of that (restricted) addition operation.

Comment: Do we not apply scalar multiplication to terms that don't have a variable e.g., c(6u+8) = 6cu + 8?

Comment: @ManuelLopez that is incorrect.  You should review carefully the definition of the vector space structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Where is the question "Is (6cu+8c) really equal to 6(cu)+8?" coming from?

Comment: Where is the question coming from?  From the definition given in the problem statement of what it means to actually be an element of $S$.  With your given example of $a=6$ and $b=8$ to be in $S$ is defined as being in "*the solution set of the equation y=ax+b, S={(x, y) ∈R^2: y=ax+b}*"... from the first line of your problem statement... in other words $(x,y)\in S\iff y=6x+8$

Comment: Here... we were wanting to prove that if $(u,6u+8)\in S$ that it implies that $c(u,6u+8)\in S$ for every value of $c$... that is... if it is true that $6u+8=6\cdot u + 8$ that it follows that $c(6u+8) = 6(cu) + 8$... and the punchline is that it *doesn't*... Simple algebra shows that after subtracting and cancelling, you would be left with $8c = 8$ which is not true for most values of $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned a vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$), so this is an abelian group, i.e., you need an (additive) identity. Since you are considering a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the identity is clearly $(0,0)$, i.e., the zero vector. The rest follows from what has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

- If $b\neq 0$, then $0\notin S$.
- If $b=0$ then it's a vector space (namely the range space of the linear map $x\mapsto ax$)

Comment: Why is 0 not in S if b is a nonzero number?

Comment: Does $x=0$ and $y=0$ satisfy $y=6x+8$?

Comment: @ManuelLopez because $0=a\cdot 0+b$ is false for $b\neq 0$ and so $(0,0)$ is not in the solution set of $y=ax+b$